# Must jQuery be verbose?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I see a lot of jQuery code like this:

```
if $('#contactme').attr('checked') {
    $(':radio').attr('disabled', false)
}
else {
    $(':radio').attr('disabled', true)
}
```

...but why not do it this way:

```
var checked =  $('#contactme').attr('checked');
$(':radio').attr('disabled', not checked);
```

...or even this way:

```
$(':radio').attr('disabled', not $('#contactme').attr('checked'));
```

Is that not possible, or is it considered ugly/hard to maintain?

### UPDATE

To the assertion that "not" should be "!" (a la C#, etc.), what about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/UVXhA/

...where this works to jQueryUI-ify the button:

```
$("button:not(:ui-button)").button();
```

...but this:

```
$("button:!(:ui-button)").button();
```

...does not (or should I say, "does !")?

Comment: Well, it would be `!checked`, not `not checked`, but it depends on which is more readable. I generally prefer the last option.

Comment: Because "your way" is YOUR opinion.

Comment: ... What's the point of the question? This has nothing to do with "jQuery", or even "JavaScript", rather "somebody got lazy". At best this is a codereview.stackexchange.com question. To answer the question, obviously jQuery doesn't have to be verbose, just like any other code.

Comment: Should use `.prop()` over `.attr()` in any case.

Comment: I'd argue your second and third options are correct - but not very maintainable. If I have to understand that code you wrote 6 months ago, it'll take me a while to grasp what super-clever and extra-concise approach you've used here - while your code snippet #1 is immediately clear, even to a jQuery novice and even after 12 months ...

Comment: @MarcB: whose opinion? I never gave an opinion on which way *I* preferred.

Comment: @UewB: Why is prop preferred over attr?

Comment: @Jason P: please czech out my update.

Comment: `:not()` is a jQuery selector. `!` is the javascript "not" operator, which inverts a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, so long as you use `!` and not `not`.

```
$(':radio').attr('disabled', !$('#contactme').attr('checked'));
```

This has nothing to do with *jQuery*, it's just how people write things.